# Undefined variable in part of the loop, output

Tags: javascript, loops

I am a beginner in JS and I am wondering why the first loop result, outputs an "undefined" variable but the rest have the"bottles" included. It is meant to output a statement, from 99 to 1.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```js
/*
 * Programming Quiz: 99 Bottles of Juice (4-2)
 *
 * Use the following `while` loop to write out the song "99 bottles of juice".
 * Log your lyrics to the console.
 *
 * Note
 *   - Each line of the lyrics needs to be logged to the same line.
 *   - The pluralization of the word "bottle" changes from "2 bottles" to "1 bottle" to "0 bottles".
 */

var num = 99;
let statementSplit = ((num + " " + bottles + " of juice on the wall! " + num + " " + bottles + " of juice! Take one down, pass it around... "));
while (num > 0) {
  var bottles = (num > 1 ? "bottles" : "bottle");
  statementSplit += ((num + " " + bottles + " of juice on the wall! " + num + " " + bottles + " of juice! Take one down, pass it around... "));
  // var statementSplit=((num+" "+bottles+" of juice on the wall! " + num + " "+ bottles+" of juice! Take one down, pass it around... "));
  num = num - 1;
}
console.log(statementSplit);
```

Comment: Do not use all caps for titles or really any significant portion of your post.

Comment: `bottles` is `undefined` when you first declare `statementSplit`.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

The `bottles` is not encased in double quotes in your `let statementSplit...` line the very first time that you call it. Instead, it should be

```
let statementSplit = ((num + " bottles of juice on the wall! " + num + " bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the edited snippet. The bottles should be added as a string and not as a variable when it is declared in the beginning.

```js
/*
 * Programming Quiz: 99 Bottles of Juice (4-2)
 *
 * Use the following `while` loop to write out the song "99 bottles of juice".
 * Log your lyrics to the console.
 *
 * Note
 *   - Each line of the lyrics needs to be logged to the same line.
 *   - The pluralization of the word "bottle" changes from "2 bottles" to "1 bottle" to "0 bottles".
 */

var num = 99;
let statementSplit = ((num + " bottles of juice on the wall! " + num + " bottles of juice! Take one down, pass it around... "));
while (num > 0) {
  var bottles = (num > 1 ? "bottles" : "bottle");
  statementSplit += ((num + " " + bottles + " of juice on the wall! " + num + " " + bottles + " of juice! Take one down, pass it around... "));
  // var statementSplit=((num+" "+bottles+" of juice on the wall! " + num + " "+ bottles+" of juice! Take one down, pass it around... "));
  num = num - 1;
}
console.log(statementSplit);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated by other you indeed have an undefined variable in the first `statementSplit` assignment.
I would move the first `statementSplit` assignment inside the while loop as well, as to increase maintainability (in case you need to change the lyrics in the future):

```
var num = 99;
let statementSplit = "";
while (num > 0) {
    var bottles = (num > 1 ? "bottles" : "bottle");
    statementSplit += ((num + " " + bottles + " of juice on the wall! " + num + " " + bottles + " of juice! Take one down, pass it around... "));
    num = num - 1;
}
console.log(statementSplit);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace "let" with "var" , with var java script allow "hoisting" ...